# Create virtual machines with Windows Azure php sdk

Tags: azure

I am trying to figuring out how to create virtual machines with windows azure php sdk https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php , I can't seem to understand on how to do this as there is any mention about virtual machines in the sdk.
Any help will be very apreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Can you use a framework to that like Chef, Puppet or Docker?

Answer (score 2):

The Azure-SDK-for-PHP offers Service Management (see https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php/blob/master/README.md) to spin up app services or VM’s. I’m not sure if it already includes support for managing Docker containers, but since it’s all REST API in the background, it should not take too much time to write a few lines to have it do the same thing. But for VM’s you can definitely manage them through the SDK.

If you need code samples, ping me. I’d love to share my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I think azure-php-sdk is for using azure storage etc. it's not for creating VM.
Normally to create VM throught management portal and Windows azure powershell.